# CGAffineTransformScale doesn't reset

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, cgaffinetransform

I use this code at `viewDidLoad` to scale my `UIImageView`:

```
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 3.0, 3.0);
```

Now, I want to go back to its original size, 1.0

I use this action for an `UIButton`

```
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.0, 1.0);
```

But doesn't work. What the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you just want to scale the size , use `CGAffineTransformMakeScale` is easy and will solve your problem.

Comment: life saver thanks so much! This method takes the reference scale from the original identity so calling it over and over doesn't make it smaller and smaller. Nick one!

Answer (score 7):

Every time you scale an image, you have to take the new scale into account.  You're first setting the scale to 3x the normal size.  Then you're setting it to 1x the "new" size.  To go back to the original size, use:

```
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
```

Comment: Thanks for CGAffineTransformidentity!